# Using iloc with pandas styler

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-styles

I currently have:

```
def color_cell(val):
    color = 'lightgreen' if val ==0 else 'white'
    return 'background-color: %s' % color

s = df.style.applymap(color_cell)
```

Which gives the following dataframe:

[image]

I want to use [pandas.dataframe.iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) to cherry pick which values are highlighted. For instance use `df.iloc[0,1]` and `df.iloc[1,2]` so that only these values are highlighted.

How can I update this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Only label-based slicing is supported right now, not positional." see the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Finer-Control:-Slicing)

A work around could looks like this:

```
# sample data
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':np.random.randint(0,4,5),
                   'col1':np.random.randint(0,4,5),
                   'col2':np.random.randint(0,4,5)})

def color_cell(df):
    return 'background-color: lightgreen'

df.style.applymap(color_cell, subset=(0,'col')).applymap(color_cell, subset=(1,'col2'))
```

[image]